# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject - In Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm Getting an error in running of Test Class but the functionality in class working as expected:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

The below query is giving an error:

```
Case testhadoverCaseOwner = [select id,OwnerId,CaseNumber,ET_Original_Case_Number__c from Case where ET_Is_Created_From_Handover__c = true AND ET_Original_Case_Number__c = :c.CaseNumber];
```

```java
public class ET_CreateCaseComments {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ET_Case_Comment__c createCaseComm(String Name, String caseCommentCategory, String caseCommentDescription, String caseId) {
                
        ET_Case_Comment__c caseComment = new ET_Case_Comment__c(Name = Name, ET_Comment_Category__c = caseCommentCategory, ET_Comment_Description__c = caseCommentDescription, Case__c = caseId);
        insert casecomment;
                
        Case c = [select id, OwnerId, CaseNumber, ET_Original_Case_Number__c from Case where id = :caseId LIMIT 1];
        if(c.ET_Original_Case_Number__c == null){
              if(caseCommentCategory == 'Handover'){
                    if(c.CaseNumber != null){
                        
                    //error comes on the below query line
                    Case testhadoverCaseOwner = [select id, OwnerId, CaseNumber, ET_Original_Case_Number__c from Case where ET_Is_Created_From_Handover__c = true AND ET_Original_Case_Number__c = :c.CaseNumber];
                    Set<String> userIds = new Set<String>();
                    userIds.add(testhadoverCaseOwner.OwnerId);
                    ET_CreateCaseComments.notifyUsers(userIds, testhadoverCaseOwner.Id, testhadoverCaseOwner.CaseNumber);
                            
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```java
@isTest
public class ET_CreateCaseCommentsTest {

    @isTest public static void caseCommentsTest() {
                
        Id recordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('EMEA Servicing').getRecordTypeId(); 
        Case cs = new Case();
        cs.ET_Request_Type__c = 'RCF Rollover, Increase, Decrease';
        cs.ET_Submitting_Team__c = 'Secondary Trading (EMEA & APAC)';
        cs.ET_Is_this_a_NAD_client__c = 'Yes';
        cs.ET_Facility_Type__c = 'New';
        cs.ET_Submitting_Region__c = 'EMEA';
        cs.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
        cs.ET_Urgency_flag__c = true;
        cs.ET_Acknowledgement__c = true;
        cs.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        cs.Status = 'New';
        cs.ET_Is_Created_From_Handover__c = false;
        cs.ET_Original_Case_Number__c ='';
        insert cs;
        ET_CreateCaseComments.createCaseComm('Test', 'Handover', 'Testing Case Comments', cs.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You experience that error when you assign a SOQL query to a single record but the query doesn't find any results.

One way to prevent this is to assign the results of the query to a List (in your scenario `List<Case>`) that way even if the query doesn't return results you won't get the error, but then later you will have to access the first record returned.

One little detail, if you're filtering by ID in your query, your query is already Limited to return 1 result due to the unique nature of ID's so stating LIMIT 1 is redundant with applying a filter by ID.

In the context of your test the case you're creating has the isCreatedFromHandover boolean marked to false but in the query you're filtering to those that have that boolean as true so that might be the reason it's not showing up, ensure that the records you want to show met all the criteria on the query.